# Use SHA1 for the purpose of shorting a string

Tags: sha

Had a scenario where I need to call a vendor rest api, a key attribute has a definition of 40 in length however my upstream mapping field is of length ~500, was thinking to use SHA1 to hash it, so that the upstream value always able to map to the shorter version of downstream field. Any flaw with this design? Thanks!

Comment: You are aware that SHA1 is irreversible, meaning you cannot recover the original input String?

Answer (score 0):

Collisions. `H(a) == H(b)` can hold when `a != b`.

It might be better to have a map table of upstream value to vendor value which would work at least as long as there are less than 256**40 distinct values in the upstream field of a 500 bytes.